# Weblogic work manager to fixed thread pool service

Tags: concurrency, weblogic, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, workmanagertaskexecutor

I have recently converted weblogic work manager to java concurreny fixed thread pool.  I have come across work manager task executer of spring. Could you give me a reason why it is using over direct thread pool

Comment: could you give more details about "converted weblogic work manager to java concurreny fixed thread pool"?

Answer (score 0):

There is one project which is running on weblogic server and for multithreading , concurrent work manager implemented which is given by weblogic oracle   .

Now the requirement is to remove weblogic dependencies from project, which indirectly leads to removal of weblogic concurrent work manager and implemented with java concurrency using fixed thread pool.

now the question is , there is work manager task executor as well in java concurrency which has same implementation provided by weblogic concurrent work manager.
Which is best approach to do